# Checbox is automatically showing as selected in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listener, expandablelistview

I have a ExpandableListView that has only one child and max 2 groups 
this child has a groupview with 4-5 checkboxes - all groupview are using the same childview

When I check a element in first child  and I scroll down I see that the same element is showing as selected in second group
I repeat is showing as selected, its not calling a listener just showing as checked

I read that this is a scroll bug in listview, but I see all have the problem that its calling the listener for me its not calling the listener just showing as selected when I scroll

[The yellow its the other group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Kx6.png)

After I initialize the view I always set all checkbox to false  and the listener to null and then I check what should be checked and initialize the listener

and is not happening in all devices in my Pixel 2 XL is working fine but not in Pixel 2, Samsung s6 is having the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general issue of recycling lists. This appears on scroll when system decide reuse child cells in the list.

To avoid such issue you simply have to save the state of each cell with the checkbox. For example, you can save state inside the element OR if you have something like id(simple unique identificator) simply create HashSet and manage state there.
For example, on "check" action, you have to add your id to HashSet and on "uncheck" action delete specific id from the set.
And in your onBindViewHolder you have to check HashSet.conntains(id) to know is this cell "checked".

Comment: Not appearing on Pixel 2 XL because of the big screen.

Comment: Thanks I think that was the issue, you need to save the state and return it back when needed